# Laptop does not turn off

Tags: 22.04, laptop, hp

I have recently installed ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a new HP ZBook Power G9 laptop with an NVIDIA RTX A2000 graphics card. When I try to shut down or restart the laptop, the screen freezes showing the HP and wolf security logos.

Comment: Please do not _answer_ your own question by **editing** the question.  You might post an answer to your own question, an accept that (when you have enough point to do so... )

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the graphic card driver. Despite downloading the NVIDIA driver that was compatible with my system, I had to manually change from Intel to NVIDIA by typing `prime-select nvidia`. After that I was able to shut down and restart my machine.